# SQL SUM Distinct duplication issue and then convert to linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have an issue which i m trying to code round.

I need the sum of the price where a widget click has happened so wrote the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(Price)
FROM
(select distinct (wc.id), rp.Price  from Widgetclicks wc
join RetailerProducts rp on wc.ProductId = rp.ProductId
join ManufacturerWidgets mw on wc.ManufacturerWidgetId = mw.Id
where rp.RetailerId = 7 and  mw.ManufacturerId = 41 and mw.Enabled = 1 and mw.CountryId = 230 and wc.CreatedAt >= '2013-09-01 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt <= '2013-09-30 23:59:59.000'

)as total
```

However, as there are duplicates in the retailer product table it is summing all prices for that wc.Id.

For example if I run the following query on its own:

```
select distinct (wc.id), rp.Price  from Widgetclicks wc
join RetailerProducts rp on wc.ProductId = rp.ProductId
join ManufacturerWidgets mw on wc.ManufacturerWidgetId = mw.Id
where rp.RetailerId = 7 and  mw.ManufacturerId = 41 and mw.Enabled = 1 and mw.CountryId = 230 and wc.CreatedAt >= '2013-09-01 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt <= '2013-09-30 23:59:59.000'
```

I will get results like this:

```
Id          Price
20088492    179.99
20088501    179.99
20088905    299.99
20088905    309.94
20088915    299.99
20088915    309.94
20091364    249.99
20091364    279.99
20093608    449
20093608    468.95
20093615    449
20093615    468.95
```

As you can see in some cases there is more than one id i.e.

```
 20088905   299.99
 20088905   309.94
```

What i need to do is if there is more than one price for the id i want to get the first one so that when I sum is not doubling up on some values.  I know there are two prices on there but I just want to grab the first one.

I will alos need to convert this to Linq.

**Edit**

Thanks to ChrisL it made me think about using the updatedDate and the following query works:

```
select sum (Price) as price  from Widgetclicks wc
left join (select ProductId, MAX(UpdatedDate)As date 
from RetailerProducts 
Group By ProductId)
rp on wc.ProductId = rp.ProductId
join ManufacturerWidgets mw on wc.ManufacturerWidgetId = mw.Id
where RetailerId = 7 and  mw.ManufacturerId = 41 and mw.Enabled = 1 and mw.CountryId = 230 and wc.CreatedAt >= '2013-09-01 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt <= '2013-09-30 23:59:59.000'
```

I hope that makes sense.

Many thanks

Comment: How do you define the "first" one in terms of choosing a price to use?

Comment: @ChrisL if i select * rather than just selecting wc.Id and rp.Price the retailerProduct table does have an UpdatedDate column so if I can I would like to use the most recent UpdatedDate

Comment: Ok, i've added an answer. Also check the link out for some pointers about converting to LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this query, it will restrict the RetailerProduct join to only include one matching row with the latest "UpdateDate"

```
SELECT SUM(Price)
FROM
(select distinct (wc.id), rp.Price  from Widgetclicks wc
join RetailerProducts rp on wc.ProductId = rp.ProductId
and rp.id = (select top 1 id from retailerProducts where productid = wc.productid order by UpdateDate desc)
join ManufacturerWidgets mw on wc.ManufacturerWidgetId = mw.Id
where rp.RetailerId = 7 and  mw.ManufacturerId = 41 
and mw.Enabled = 1 and mw.CountryId = 230 and wc.CreatedAt >= '2013-09-01 00:00:00.000' 
and wc.CreatedAt <= '2013-09-30 23:59:59.000'
)as total
```

The `TOP 1` syntax assumes MS sql server, in other databases `LIMIT 1` is used to the same effect.

As far as converting to LINQ have a read of this [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)